# Clang RecursiveASTVisitor

Tags: clang

I am working on a c++ to classless c translator.

Based on the Kaleidoscope example in LLVM, each node of the AST Tree had a codeGen() function that would generate appropriate code and return it to the parent node.

I am trying to implement similar behavior using the visitor pattern, but i need the visitor to return objects.

Any ideas on how this could be done using the `RecursiveASTVisitor`?

As an example input for the program:

```
void DrawToLayout(std::string, double, double, double, double) {}

class PCellRect {

private:
  double bottomX, bottomY, topX, topY;

public:
  PCellRect(double bX, double bY, double tX, double ty)
      : bottomX(bX), bottomY(bX), topX(bX), topY(bX) {}

  void Draw() { DrawToLayout("Rect", bottomX, bottomY, topX, topY); }
};

void Test() {

  PCellRect rectangle(1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0);

  rectangle.Draw();
}
```

Would produce this output:

```
void DrawToLayout(std::string, double, double, double, double) {}

void PCellRect_Constructor(double &bottomX, double &bottomY, double &topX,
                           double &topY, double bX, double bY, double tX,
                           double tY) {
  bottomX = bX;
  bottomY = bY;
  topX = bY;
  topY = bY;
}

void PCellRect_Draw(double &bottomX, double &bottomY, double &topX,
                    double &topY) {

  DrawToLayout("Rect", bottomX, bottomY, topX, topY);
}

void Test() {

  double rectangle_PCellRect_bottomX;
  double rectangle_PCellRect_bottomY;
  double rectangle_PCellRect_topX;
  double rectangle_PCellRect_topY;

  PCellRect_Constructor(rectangle_PCellRect_bottomX,
                        rectangle_PCellRect_bottomY, rectangle_PCellRect_topX,
                        rectangle_PCellRect_topY, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0);

  PCellRect_Draw(rectangle_PCellRect_bottomX, rectangle_PCellRect_bottomY,
                 rectangle_PCellRect_topX, rectangle_PCellRect_topY);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed, `RecursiveASTVisitor` visit functions return `bool` and that couldn't be changed. These return values play a crucial role in user-defined behaviour of the traversal. So, in this limitation I have two different options for you.

### Solution 1

This solution is based on `RecursiveASTVisitor`. You can keep `std::stringstream` (or whatever container to gather results sequentially) as a member object of the visitor and write modified statements/declarations as you traverse the tree.

```cpp
class Translator : public RecursiveASTVisitor<Translator> {
public:
  bool VisitCXXConstructExpr(clang::CXXConstructExpr *ConstructorCall) {
    auto *Constructor = ConstructorCall->getConstructor();
    auto *ConstructedClass = Constructor->getParent();

    for (auto &Member : getMembers(ConstructedClass)) {
      SS << declareMember(Member) << "\n";
    }
    SS << "\n";
    SS << callPseudoConstructor(Constructor) << "\n";
  }

  // other visit functions

private:
  std::stringstream SS;
};
```

### Solution 2

This solution is a bit more complex, but gives a lot more freedom. It is based on the idea of implementing your own `RecursiveASTVisitor`. You can do this by using [StmtVisitor](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1StmtVisitor.html), [DeclVisitor](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1DeclVisitor.html), [TypeVisitor](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1TypeVisitor.html), and [TypeLocVisitor](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1TypeLocVisitor.html). These are *only* visitors, so they call correct visit function for one node, but not for its children. In order to implement your own traversal, you'll need to call `Visit` for all the child nodes that you want to traverse.

In the following snippet, I use not all `Visitor` classes (`const` versions of those, actually):

```cpp
/// Some custom object to be constructed for each AST node
class TranslatedNode {
  // ...
};

class Translator : public ConstStmtVisitor<Translator, TranslatedNode>,
                   public ConstDeclVisitor<Translator, TranslatedNode> {
public:
  TranslatedNode VisitCXXConstructExpr(clang::CXXConstructExpr *ConstructorCall) {
    TranslatedNode Result;

    auto *Constructor = Constructor->getConstructor();
    auto *ConstructedClass = Constructor->getParent();

    for (auto &Member : getMembers(ConstructedClass)) {
      Result.declareMember(Member);
    }

    Result.startCall(getPseudoConstructor(Constructor);
    for (auto &Member : getMembers(ConstructedClass)) {
      Result.addArgument(Member);
    }
    for (auto *Argument : ConstructorCall->arguments()) {
      Result.addArgument(Visit(Argument));
    }

    return Result;
  }

  // other visit functions
};
```

This is a pseudo-code in a way, but I hope you get the idea.

The first approach is easier and whenever you can implement something in terms of `RecursiveASTVisitor` you should do it. However, in cases like yours, I do think that sooner or later it will require more control from the traversal.

I hope that this information will be useful for your project. Happy hacking with Clang!